# How to reduce tilting in self-made gimbal

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I made a gimbal at home with PVC. Used some cement filled PVC pieces as hanging weight to make the phone steady. But when I shoot with it, I feel some tilting movements in the video due to the momentum of these weights. How can I reduce this?

Is it really possible to make a gimbal at home which can produce some decently stabilised videos? [image of gimbal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBNjH.jpg)

Comment: In order to answer your first question we really need to see the gimbal you've made. Can you upload some pictures? The second question ("is it possible") seems unnecessary: if 'yes', your first question still stands, if 'no', it doesn't. It depends on skills, materials, and tools, but you can certainly build a proper gimbal at home.

Comment: Just to clarify what you mean by "tilting", are you referring to the phone being at an angle when everything is in a fixed position, the phone being tilted while you're panning, the phone tilting momentarily when you change direction, or the phone going into an oscillating tilt when you stop moving?

Comment: What is the 'drop time' on the gimbal? How long does it take to swing down to the bottom when you hold it at 90deg initially? Should be several seconds - you want the mass at the bottom to have a moment *just* greater than the mass of your camera on the top - this means that when you are moving it around the momentum of the weight trying to swing it one way is balanced by the momentum of the camera trying to swing it the other way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess at what's happening from your description.  In general, the "moment" on both sides of the pivot (weight x distance) should be close to equal.  You can have slightly more weight at the bottom so it wants to stay upright.  Inertia is what keeps things from tilting when you start or stop moving.  If you have weight just at the bottom (or a lot more weight, like a "zero" weight phone at the top and a concrete filled pipe at the bottom), you have a pendulum, and it will react to every motion.

For mass, you could fill both the top and bottom pipes with equal amounts of concrete.  Weigh them when the concrete has dried if you can measure that weight to the ounce, or use a balance and some additional small weights to see which one is heavier and by how much.  Your phone will add a small amount of weight to the top, as will the bracket you're using to hold it.  If the weight of one pipe will be a few ounces heavier than the weight of the other plus the phone and bracket, you're in business.  Otherwise, attach a small weight to the bottom pipe so it will be a few ounces heavier than the top including the phone and bracket.

Also, be precise matching the lengths of the arms to the top and bottom pipes.  The phone doesn't weight much, but if you mount it above the top pipe, the weight will be farther from the pivot, which will magnify it.  It would be better to mount it under the top pipe to minimize that, or even better, centered between the top and bottom pipes.  If you have a gimbal in multiple planes, that would complicate putting the phone on the inside.  You could compensate for the phone's distance by adding a little more weight at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I made one for my son's camera.

The issue is usually with the bearings. I used 2 pairs of bearings taken from those "spinners" and put them on a threaded rod.

Used double nuts to "just" load the bearings to provide some damping and he had good results when he was taking videos while skiing...